# Duplicated nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a function that creates a VISIT node each time a link gets visited. I also attach some stats to this visit node, like DATE, BROWSER, OS etc.

But sometimes the Date node (or probably other nodes too) gets duplicated, meaning that I get 2 date nodes for one VISIT.

Each VISIT should only be attached to one stats node. (e.g. one browser, one date)

Here's my code:

```
MATCH (l:URL { id: $id })
CREATE (v:VISIT)
MERGE (b:BROWSER { browser: $browser })
MERGE (c:COUNTRY { country: $country })
MERGE (o:OS { os: $os })
MERGE (r:REFERRER { referrer: $referrer })
MERGE (d:DATE { date: $date })
MERGE (v)-[:VISITED]->(l)
MERGE (v)-[:BROWSED_BY]->(b)
MERGE (v)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(c)
MERGE (v)-[:OS]->(o)
MERGE (v)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(r)
MERGE (v)-[:VISITED_IN]->(d)
RETURN l
```

And here is the graph image example, VISIT (red node) should only have one VISITED_IN relationship and to only one node of that type.

[image: duplicated nodes imag]

Comment: Does it happen on high load ?

Comment: @Muldec Depends on what you mean by high load. Often several users visit a link at the same time.

Comment: That's what I meant. And does the two date nodes have the same value in their date property ?

Comment: @Muldec Yes. both have `{ date: <same date> }`.

Comment: Concurrency Issue. Merge is not Thread Safe. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge is not ThreadSafe. It basically does 3 thing in a row, but can run into concurrency issues :
1. Check if the pattern exists
2. Creates it if it does not
3. Returns it

If two merge requests come with the same pattern at the same time, it does not guarantee that only one will be created.

You should couple your merge request with a unique constraint to ensure uniqueness

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (d:Date) ASSERT d.date IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: Hmm interesting. Thank you. What can I do for other nodes where values is not unique? For example BROWSER has b.browser equal to firefox or chrome or edge. Is there a way to make sure thst my VISIT only has relation to one firefox browser?

Comment: It's the same situation. the key browser should be unique and inforced with a constraint. Unique meaning that only one occurence of a property could exist. So you could have one node with chrome, one with firefox, one with edge, the constraint is still valid as there is no two node with the same value.

Comment: Great. I can not try it right now because it gives me an error since data is not unique. I'll try after merging duplicated nodes.